# unix process run as root even though start from other users

Tags: unix

I have a script with permissions -rws--s--x

When i run the script from an user called "user1" the process always run as root.

What is the reason the script run as root and not run as the user who starts the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the "s" bit (setuid permission) - it escalates the process to run as the permission of the owner of the executable (often root) for when a regular user doesn't have permissions to do some system operation. Those are generally to be avoided because if they there's a bug/exploit on it someone can easily get root access to your system. More details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)